# iTextSharp generate pdf open file has error. the file show is damaged and could not be repaired

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

The issues i am facing when i generate the pdf and open the pdf file is show the file is damaged. after i use notepad++ to open file and i figure out inside file at the end got the html code. But if i try to remove the HTML code then the file can open. Can I know why will have this error

this is the code i use to generate pdf

```
        try
        {
            Session["ExportDetail"] = "viewnormal";
            string urlEncFolderName = Server.UrlEncode("uploads");
            string errMsg = "";

            NameTextSharp.Document doc = new NameTextSharp.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 50, 50);
            MemoryStream outstream = new MemoryStream();
            string filename = null;
            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, outstream);
            doc.Open();
            doc = BindingData(doc);

            //start - attach file if exist
            List<string> attachment = GetAttachment(Session["QUESTIONSETID"].ToString());

            if (attachment.Count() > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < attachment.Count(); i++)
                {
                    string strFilePath = "";
                    string fileExt = "";
                    strFilePath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + urlEncFolderName + "/" + attachment[i];
                    fileExt = Path.GetExtension(strFilePath);

                    // check if file exist
                    if (File.Exists(strFilePath))
                    {
                        PdfFileSpecification pdfAttch = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(wri, strFilePath, "Attachment " + (i + 1) + fileExt, null);
                        wri.AddFileAttachment(strFilePath, pdfAttch);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errMsg = "Attachment file(s) not found.";
                    }
                }
            }

            if (errMsg == "")
            {
                filename = "Sub" + Session["SUBMISSIONID"].ToString() + "_ViewAnswer";
                doc.Close();
                Response.BinaryWrite(outstream.ToArray());
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=" + filename + ".pdf"));                  
            }
            else
            {
                Messagebox("There was an error converting to PDF.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mag.WriteToLogFile("Error at export to PDF : " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

this code is when i open pdf file use notepad++ at the end code

```
                    trailer
                    <</Size 59/Root 57 0 R/Info 58 0 R/ID [<eb8dd247b7cfa23df5a2399a7d53dd86><eb8dd247b7cfa23df5a2399a7d53dd86>]>>
                    %iText-5.5.9
                    startxref
                    3043799
                    %%EOF

                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <head id="Head1"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /><title>
                        Question
                    </title><link href="../../Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you say "The PDF is corrupt after I open and save the file in Notepad++." then the answer is "**Of course, it is corrupt! One simply does not use a text editor to edit binary files!**" If the snippet you show, is the end of the PDF file you produced, then there you are doing something wrong with the output stream. All files created with iText end with `%%EOF` (that's how they should end). You are adding extra HTML code, which is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for your miss understand. actually i open the pdf file normally the file is show corrupt, then i try to use notepad++ open to check the file and i show have HTML code inside the file. when extra the file actually i not add any HTML code inside

Comment: iText doesn't produce HTML, so your allegation that iTextSharp is the culprit is false. *You* are adding that HTML, whether you believe it or not.

Comment: The stuff following the **%%EOF** in your excerpt has *not* been generated by iTextSharp which you can check also storing `outstream.ToArray()` to a file and inspecting that file. So if you don't *add any HTML code*, your framework *does*. One thing you change to help your framework is to first set content type and other headers and thereafter write the pdf stream. After all, headers are returned before content...

Comment: You **must** call `Response.End()` after `Response.AddHeader()`. Otherwise, as you've found out, the page HTML markup is appended to the PDF.

Comment: Thank you Guys! is work after add Response.End()